# Using little snitch on Cricut design space

Tags: network, firewall

I'm trying to stop Cricut Design Space constantly updating, it should run without internet access but recently there's been some changes and now it wants to connect all the time. I Just installed little snitch to see if I can stop it accessing the internet but if I block design space entirely, it wont work at all.
I've attached a picture here of the list that comes up in Little Snitch when it access the internet,  any ideas?

[image]

<sup>Click for full size</sup>

Comment: You're just going to have to disable them all then re-enable one at a time to see which it insists on. You can eliminate the most obvious trackers first, of course.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new to lil snitch so I'll work on it.